# How to combine list with static entries in deployment template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a template for a Pod with `containers` like this:

```yaml
containers:
- image: ubuntu
```

Now I want to extend this with possible sidecars. I tried:

```yaml
containers:
{{ toYaml .Values.sidecars | indent 0 }}
- image: ubuntu
```

Sadly this renders e.g. to:

```yaml
containers:
[]
- image: ubuntu
```

How can I combine the possible sidecars, to that they integrate with the static container?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this specific output because `.Values.sidecars` is an empty list.  You'd need to provide a value in your chart's `values.yaml` file or in a `helm install -f` additional values file.

If this is an expected case – your `values.yaml` declares `sidecars: []` as a default – then you can protect against the empty list with a conditional.  I like using `with` here, which will bind the expression to `.` and evaluate a block if it's truthy.

```yaml
containers:
{{- with .Values.sidecars }}
{{- . | toYaml | nindent 0 }}
{{- end }}
- name: not-a-sidecar
  image: ...
```